# remove noise/junk values in real time plot using matplotlib

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, real-time

I followed this code exactly and was able to obtain a nice real-time plot (https://gist.github.com/brandoncurtis/33a67d9d402973face8d). However, there are noise values that should not be plotted. You can see the output in the screenshot below. I can't figure out why it is plotting this. When I use the arduino sketch and test the sensor, it reads fine without the noise values. I think its because I need to include `plt.pause()` or some time delay?

[image]

[image]

```
%matplotlib notebook
import serial 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from time import time
ser = serial.Serial('com5',9600)
plt.ion()

ard_dat=[]
start_time = time()
timepoints=[]
view_time = 5 
duration = 60

fig = plt.figure()
fig.suptitle('live updated data', fontsize='18', fontweight='bold')
plt.xlabel('time, s')
plt.ylabel('reading')
plt.axes().grid(True)
line, = plt.plot(ard_dat,marker='o')
plt.xlim([0,view_time])

ser.flushInput()
run = True

while run:
    ser.reset_input_buffer()
    while (ser.inWaiting()==0):
        pass #do nothing

    srdata = ser.readline()

    try:
        intstrdata = int(srdata)

        ard_dat.append(intstrdata)
        ymin = float(min(ard_dat))-40
        ymax = float(max(ard_dat))+40
        timepoints.append(time()-start_time)
        current_time = timepoints[-1]
        line.set_xdata(timepoints)
        line.set_ydata(ard_dat)
        plt.ylim([ymin,ymax])

        if current_time > view_time:
            plt.xlim([current_time-view_time,current_time])

        if timepoints[-1] > duration: run=False



    except ValueError: pass

    fig.canvas.draw()
```

Comment: Can you please post the exact code you are using in the question?

Comment: Hi, I added the code which is basically a copy of the code I referenced in the link. I guess I should have included the code regardless of it being verbatim. Thanks for the response.

Comment: I also noticed the values seem to be read wrong, i.e. the resulting list after appending each read value is 574,465, 478, 599, 58, 4, 5, 4, 456, 566, 550... Somehow it is trimming the values and reading only the 10th and 1st digits place?

Comment: What is the line `while (ser.inWaiting()==0):` doing? It's not in the original script. If there is a reason to put it there, I guees you should do `if (ser.inWaiting()==0):  continue`.

Comment: oh great catch, for some reason I kept that from a previous code I copied to test out the sensor which I couldn't get to work. It was the one that involved drawnow, however you suggested not to use that library. i removed that line and now the plot makes more sense; it does not plot the strange outlier values. thanks!

Comment: however, now I'm experiencing an issue where the plot does not update the data as I make a change on the sensor. It just plots a straight line of dots at the last value it was set at. I thought it was working before because I didn't make a change on the sensor, however now when I deliberately try to turn the knob on the pot sensor, it doesn't change.

Comment: So the animation is correct if you simply start it, and only if you change your settings on the sensor, it becomes all constant? Or does it not work correctly even when not changing any sensor settings?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150555/discussion-between-spencer-trinh-and-importanceofbeingernest).